What is the profinite completion of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?
Let $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be the polynomial ring in $X$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers.  Its profinite completion is the inverse limit over all ideals of finite index. So, what is the profinite completion $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}[X]}$ of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$? Is it $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}[[X]]$? Is $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}[X]}$ a Noetherian ring?

You can do similar computations as in the case of the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, as $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is factorial, an ideal $I$ may be written in the form $\wp_1^{e_1} \dots \wp_r^{e_r}$, with $\wp_i$ distinct prime ideals. If $I$ is of finite index, then each $\wp_i^{e_i}$ is of finite index too, by the chinese remainder theorem. Hence each $\wp_i$ is of finite index.

If $\wp$ is a prime ideal of finite index, then $\mathbb{Z} \cap \wp$ is a non zero prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, thus of the form $(p)$, and $\wp$ contains $p$. Moreover, the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\wp$ is a finite integral domain, thus is a finite field. Hence $\wp$ is of the form $(p,P)$, such that $P$ is irreducible mod $p$, and $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\wp \cong \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(\overline{P})$.

We are ready to compute $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}[X]}$. By the chinese remainder theorem, it is isomorphic to $\prod_{\wp} \mathbb{Z}[X]^{\wedge, \wp}$, where the product is taken over every prime $\wp$ of finite index, and $\mathbb{Z}[X]^{\wedge, \wp}$ is the completion for the $\wp$-adic topology, that is, $$\underset{\leftarrow}{\textrm{lim}} \ \mathbb{Z}[X] / \wp^n.$$
If $\wp=(p,P)$, and you follow the computation made in Completion of a polynomial ring w.r.t. a maximal ideal, you will find that $$\mathbb{Z}[X]^{\wedge,\wp} \cong \mathbb{Z}[X] [\![X_1,X_2]\!]/(p-X_1,P-X_2) \cong \mathbb{Z_p}[X][\![P]\!]. $$
Thus, you find the isomorphisms $$\widehat{\mathbb{Z}[X]} \cong \prod_p \prod_{P} \mathbb{Z}_p[X][\![P]\!], $$
where $p$ ranges over all primes, and $P$ ranges over all polynomials that are irreducible mod $p$.

Every finite field is a residue field of this ring, hence it is not isomorphic to $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}[\![X]\!]$, for which only prime finite fields are residue fields. It is not a noetherian ring, as it is an infinite product of non trivial rings.

Therefore, even its pro-p completion (i.e. the inverse limit over all ideals of finite index of $p$-power) is not Noetherian?

Indeed, its pro-$p$ completion is not noetherian

@EnguerrandMoulinier. Can you elaborate about the existence of a decomposition of a nonzero ideal into the product of prime ideals and how it relates to factoriality ?

@GreginGre You are right to ask the question, as it is a mistake ; it is not true that every ideal in a UFD has a decomposition into primes. However, I have been able to correct my error. Here is my statement ;
Every ideal of finite index in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a product of primes.
More generally, I believe that in a noetherian ring $A$ that is integrally closed in its field of fractions, then any finite index ideal has a decomposition into primes, but I still need to work out some details.
I will add those corrections

How is $(2,x^2)$ a product of primes?

@Aphelli Hello, no it's not. I need to edit my post ; the final isomorphism still holds, but instead of writing ideals as a product of primes, I need to write them as intersections of primary ideals. Things almost do not change, as if $Q$ is a primary ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ of finite index, then $\sqrt{Q}$ is prime of finite index, thus maximal, of the form $\wp$ as in my post. Then I may show that $I$ contains a product of primes, and things will pass to the limit

@Aphelli The key observation is that in the ring $\mathbb Z [X]$ products of primes form a final subposet of all finite index ideals, so computing the completion can be reduced to taking limit of quotients by only those ideals which are products of primes. The relevant notion is of cofiltered limit — limit of a diagram where every finite subdiagram already has a cone.

@xsnl: you’re right, good point!
